How to set Visual Studio to create new files as UTF-8 as default?
Is there any way to configure Visual Studio 2022 so that any kind of new file created from within the IDE will be UTF-8 encoded as default?
I personally find very annoying to stumble upon the same problem: I'm working on a ASP+React TypeScript project, so I have *.cs, *.ts, *.tsx, but also JSONs and other files. Apparently, when a new file is created, its encoding is Western Europe codepage. Thus, when I type a string like "caffè", it is rendered as "caff?" (something like that).
However, that's not just a aestethic/readability problem. I had to solve a bug where the comparison between two string failed, because the different encodings. Very annoying.
Sub-question: in our globalized world, is there any shortcoming to use UTF-8 as standard, and leave the single-byte/codepage encoding as esplicit demand?

Dupes: How to config visual studio to use UTF-8 as the default encoding for all projects? and How to set standard encoding in Visual Studio

@RemyLebeau thanks for pointing me out those links. However, the second one is outdated, because in VS 2022 there's no a real selection, but only a generic Unicode: what kind of Unicode? with or without BOM? About the first one, it seems that VS doesn't follow completely the EditorConfig rules: if I put the config in a parent folder, the rules should be valid for all the descendent solutions, but that's not apparently.
